Tampermonkey hide DIV: Google Docs side panel toggle
I would like to hide a DIV using TamperMonkey.
On Google Docs the sheet off paper is off-center only to accomodate the product-placement toggle for the side panel (the '<' in the bottom right).
In Chrome, I can (right click -> ) inspect this obnoxious product-pushing button, which turns out to be called companion-collapser-button-container and then set display: none;.
Of course this only works until I reload the page (by [Chrome] design).
How can I permanently set the DIV called  companion-collapser-button-container to display: none; using TamperMonkey?


Create a new TamperMonkey User Script, then in the header set it to apply to Google Docs:
// @match        https://docs.google.com/document/d/*

Also in the header load GM_addStyle (GM = GreaseMonkey; the original TamperMonkey):
// @grant        GM_addStyle

Then simply set:
    GM_addStyle('div.companion-collapser-button-container { display: none; }');

EDIT: downloadable file
Full code:
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Google Docs Side Panel
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      2024-04-21
// @description  Hide the Google Docs Side Panel (Calendar, Keep, Maps, etc.) toggle button for a clean slate.
// @author       Bastiaan Quast
// @match        https://docs.google.com/document/d/*
// @icon         none
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    GM_addStyle('div.companion-collapser-button-container { display: none; }');
})();

